# Duplicate call in select-sql-parameter-source

Tags: spring-integration

I'm working with a dynamic query, using select-sql-parameter-source to search the information that I need.

This is my configuration:

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER.LASTUPDATE_ACTIVE &lt; TO_DATE(:last_process_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS') "     
    channel="headerEnricher.customerBR01"
    update="" 
    row-mapper="customerRowMapper"
    data-source="jdbcTemplate"
    max-rows-per-poll="0"
    select-sql-parameter-source="parameterSource.customerBR01">
    <!-- Cron Time -->
    <int:poller fixed-rate="50" time-unit="SECONDS">
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

<!-- This is to get last process date -->
<bean id="parameterSource.customerBR01" factory-bean="parameterSourceFactory.customerBR01" factory-method="createParameterSourceNoCache">
    <constructor-arg value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="parameterSourceFactory.customerBR01" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
    <property name="parameterExpressions">
        <map>
            <!-- Here we get the last process date -->
            <entry key="last_process_date" value="@hsqlHistoricProcessServiceDateDAO.getLastProcessDate(3,1,'CUSTOMER')" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I was looking that loggin appeared twice, so I changed my code in this function :

hsqlHistoricProcessServiceDateDAO.getLastProcessDate

To return only an account variable. 
Code of function hsqlHistoricProcessServiceDateDAO.getLastProcessDate is the following:

```
private int contador = 0;

public String getLastProcessDate(Integer country, Integer business, String tableName) {
    contador++;

    System.out.println("Contador "+ contador);

    return Integer.toString(contador);
}
```

And its result is :

```
Contador 1
Contador 2
```

So, this method is called twice, and I need only one call, because in the "real code" I have all logging twice for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case, you don't need to disable the cache; use this instead...

```
<bean id="parameterSource.customerBR01" 
    factory-bean="parameterSourceFactory.customerBR01"
    factory-method="createParameterSource">
        <constructor-arg value="" />
</bean>
```

The `...NoCache` version is needed when the same key is used in multiple parameters and you want each one to be re-evaluated.

Disabling the cache has this additional side-effect because the `getValue()` method is called twice for each use of the key. One call is from `NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters()`; the second is from `NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray()`.

Comment: Hi Gary. 

I think that in my logic is not possible this solution, and I need to use NoCache. 

Because in the "real code" of this function @hsqlHistoricProcessServiceDateDAO.getLastProcessDate(3,1,'CUSTOMER'), I search into an embedded databases an specific value, and this value change after each inbound execution.

If I put "createParameterSource" the value will be the same in each execution and I need the real changed value.

Comment: Hmmm... yes, of course. Unfortunately, there's nothing we can do in the integration framework without a change to the Spring Framework itself (we'll open a JIRA over there). Until that's resolved, I am afraid you will need to add your own logic in `getLastProcessDate ` to cache the first call and clear the cache after the second call.